# playwright python page source frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

This is my first post
I hope to find the solution
This is just a small script code
I want to display the page source code inside the frame

I have tried to use page.content()  The results did not show me errors in the page example

Enter a valid phone number.

I'm trying to learn playwright

```
import time

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.icloud.com/")

    page.click('body > div:nth-child(5) > ui-main-pane > div > div.root-component > div > div > main > div > div.landing-page-content > ui-button')
    page.click(
      'body > div:nth-child(5) > ui-main-pane > div > div.root-component > div > div > div > div > div > div.create > a')
    time.sleep(3)

    frame=page.frame_locator('#create-account-frame')

    firstName = frame.locator('#firstNameInput > div > idms-textbox > idms-error-wrapper > div > div > input')
    firstName.fill('firstName')
    lastname = frame.locator('#widget > div.create-form > idms-step > div > div > div > div.idms-step-content > div > div > div.flow-section.account-info-section > div > div.form-table > div > div > full-name > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > last-name-input > div > idms-textbox > idms-error-wrapper > div > div > input')
    lastname.fill('lastname')
    Continue = frame.locator(
        '#widget > div.create-form > idms-step > div > div > div > div.idms-step-footer.clearfix > idms-toolbar > div > div > div > button.button.button-primary.last.nav-action.pull-right.weight-medium')
    Continue.click()

    page.content()
    print(page.content())




    time.sleep(1000000)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want inner html in frame  #create-account-frame